# Phone no verification without sms gateway in parse

Tags: android, iphone, parse-platform, sms-gateway

I am using a free server of parse.com for my database

I need to verify phone number of user without spending any money, because I don't want to buy an sms gateway, or mobile no. verification by using miss call service.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

How is sending verification codes to a user's email address going to verify their phone number? The only way to verify that a user owns the phone number that they're giving is to actually call or text it and have the user respond (usually by entering a one time passcode that's in the text message or spoken in the phone call).

Parse already supports e-mail verification, so if you want to do that then you can check it out here: http://blog.parse.com/2012/04/03/introducing-app-email-settings/

*Some* - but not all - mobile networks let you send SMS messages via e-mail address, but support for this is rather variable. For near-certain delivery and the best user experience you'll need to use a service that lets you send SMS messages through an API, such as [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com).

Comment: Oh, sorry I combined phone number verification to email verification, I edited my question. You mean to say there is no option other than to buy an sms gateway like Twilio that takes 0.01$ for 1 sms. Thanks for your answer